# Influxdata Telegraf not connecting to Kafka Broker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, telegraf

I have an application setup, where I have one zookeeper,one kafka broker and one telegraf instance. They are running on aws EC2 instances as docker containers. When I try to connect my telegraf container to kafka broker I am getting below error.

> [telegraf] Error running agent: starting input inputs.kafka_consumer: create consumer: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: dial tcp 172.18.0.3:19092: connect: connection refused

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      # ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper:2888:3888

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "29093:29093"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://:29093,INTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://<EC2 IP ADDRESS>:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  telegraf:
    image: telegraf:latest
    hostname: telegraf
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    container_name: telegraf
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
networks:
  kafka_network:
    name: kafka_docker_network
```

telegraf.conf

```
# Configuration for telegraf agent
[agent]
## Removed other stuffs for brevity 
[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
## Kafka brokers.
  brokers = ["kafka:9092"]
  topics = ["orders"]
  max_message_len = 1000000
  data_format = "json"
```

Comment: 1) remove `9092:9092`. It's not needed since that port is only exposed within the Docker network, not your host. 2) Error doesn't match your config. Where is port 19092 coming from?